# Getting custom rss feed item element with syndicationitem?

Tags: c#

I have an RSS feed like so:

```
<item>
<title>
Ellen celebrates the 20th anniversary of coming out episode
</title>
<link>
http://www.dailymail.co.uk/video/tvshowbiz/video-1454179/Ellen-celebrates-20th-anniversary-coming-episode.html?ITO=1490&ns_mchannel=rss&ns_campaign=1490
</link>
<description>
Ellen celebrates 20th anniversary of coming out episode on her old sitcom 'Ellen'. Ellen said she cried during rehearsals but urged everyone to stay true to themselves and it will benefit you in the long term.
</description>
<enclosure url="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2017/04/27/00/3FA409EA00000578-0-image-m-21_1493249529333.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="7972"/>
<pubDate>Thu, 27 Apr 2017 00:45:14 +0100</pubDate>
<guid>
http://www.dailymail.co.uk/video/tvshowbiz/video-1454179/Ellen-celebrates-20th-anniversary-coming-episode.html?ITO=1490&ns_mchannel=rss&ns_campaign=1490
</guid>
<media:description/>
<media:thumbnail url="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2017/04/27/00/3FA409EA00000578-0-image-m-21_1493249529333.jpg" width="154" height="115"/>
<media:credit scheme="urn:ebu">YouTube</media:credit>
<media:content url="http://video.dailymail.co.uk/video/mol/2017/04/26/4464646762446275941/1024x576_MP4_4464646762446275941.mp4" type="video/mp4" medium="video" duration="245" lang="en"/>
</item>
```

I am trying to get the url value of media:content, when I loop through the syndication items like so:

```
            foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
            {

                foreach (SyndicationElementExtension extension in item.ElementExtensions)
                {
                    XElement ele = extension.GetObject<XElement>();
                    MessageBox.Show(ele.Value);
                }


            }
```

I get blank data, how can I get the url of the media content?

Comment: You need to get the attribute not the value of the element and you should check for the media content.

Comment: instead of `ele.Value` have you tried `ele.Attribute("url") ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

have you tried:

```
XElement ele = extension.GetObject<XElement>();
if (ele.Name.LocalName == "content")
{
   MessageBox.Show(ele.Attribute("url").Value);
}
```

Comment: One suggestion: using `(string) ele.Attribute("url")` isntead of the `Value` property guards against `ArgumentNullExceptions` in the case where the attribute is not declared.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var item in feed.Items)
{
    var content = item.ElementExtensions
                      .FirstOrDefault(ext => ext.OuterName == "content")
                      .GetObject<XmlElement>().InnerText    
}
```